Google Colab giving "request had invalid authentication" error even when set so that anyone can edit with link
When sharing Google Colab links, after the document is set to "anyone with the link can edit", recipients are getting the following message when they click on the link:
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
My attempts to trouble-shoot this are failing, as it leads to a bunch of developer stuff that is beyond my knowledge.  I'm just trying to share Python notebooks with students after commenting on them, but many are running into this problem.
I tried Googling the problem, but I find a bunch of developer stuff about APIs, etc. that does not directly involve Colab.  This does not seem to apply.  I found one other question about this error with Colab, but the only reply basically said that the question was not clear.  When I click on the link there is no problem, nor is there a problem when I switch browsers.
